# O2 sensor not connected

Tags: o2-sensor, no-crank-no-start

Just change manifold on an 2002 Hyundai santa fe. One of the o2 sensor is not hook up. The car start ed drive around corner car act like it was choking and stop. Now car wont start up

Comment: Connect the O2 sensor...

Comment: You just did a load of work on this car, it's much more likely that there is something else wrong than an O2 sensor causing that issue. Scan your OBD codes and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

A disconnected O2 sensor would never prevent a car from starting. The computer would see the lack of o2 response and stay in OPEN LOOP mode.